# Show activities on users' posted content

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I would like to provide a view, and something like a newsletter, where the users can see what actions (e.g. commented) are done on their posted content.

I thought I could do this with [Activity](http://drupal.org/project/activity), but I can only catch the events the users did on their posts.
Do have any idea on how to provide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module called [Heartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/heartbeat) that should achieve what you're looking for.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... displays **user activity** on a website. This module is an API to log activity. The logged data contains message structures, attributes and variables. Once the activity messages exist in the database, they will be parsed and build into activity streams.

Comment: Thanx MikeNGarrett, that's what i'm looking for, but there's one problem: Heartbeat does not provide a views3 implementation and the downgrade to views2 is almost impossible. Does anybody know how to get this working in views3?

Comment: You're just going to have to wait. Most people I know aren't jumping on the Drupal 7 platform yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're right. Pity!